# Does BO 4.2 SP8 support Java11?

Tags: java, upgrade, business-objects

I want to upgrade BusinessObjects from 4.2 SP2 to 4.2 SP8. I am currently using Java8 and going to upgrade to Java11. Are these compatible with each other ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me the **highest version supported in 4.2 and 4.3 is Java 8** according to their respective Product Availability Matrix documents...

[SAP BusinessObjects BI Platform 4.2 Supported Platforms (PAM)](https://support.sap.com/content/dam/launchpad/en_us/pam/pam-essentials/SBOP_BI_42.pdf)

{SAP BusinessObjects BI Platform 4.3 Supported Platforms (PAM)} https://support.sap.com/content/dam/launchpad/en_us/pam/pam-essentials/SBOP_BI_43.pdf)

Have a look for yourself. I could be reading it wrong.

SAP is moving away needing Java at all and recommends you switch to the HTML interface for Web Intelligence. This [blog post](https://dscallards.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/17000082004-sap-official-position-regarding-sap-businessobjects-web-intelligence-java-applet-viewer) goes into this topic in detail.

When we upgraded from 4.1 SP06 Patch 4 to 4.2 SP07 Patch 4  recently we just switched all users over to HTML in order to not have to mess with Java anymore.